# Why pair is required to insert into map?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, std-pair

Though I do not dislike it, but find it inconvinient to declare a `pair<X,Y>` object, or make a call to `make_pair`, in order to call `map::insert`. Why `insert` doesn't take two arguments instead to specify Key and Value respectively.

While I understand it is for compatibility with other STL containers, that exhibit `value_type`. But `find` method takes `key_type` which breaks this compatibility assertion. `map` has both `key_type` and `mapped_type`, so why cant `map` have:

```
iterator insert(const key_type&, const mapped_type&);
```

Yes, there are overloads of `insert` taking iterator(s). But this two-argument `insert` could have been mixed well.

Just one advantage I see is: less call stack usage.

**EDIT**: 
Just found out that `insert` is the *only* method that takes `value_type`, that is `pair<X,Y>`. Many other methods like `find`, `erase`, `at`, `count`, `equal_range`, `lower_bound`, `upper_bound` and `operator[]` take `key_type`.

Comment: You can now use `map.emplace(key, value)`.

Comment: @Simple: `emplace` is actually more general. You can pass weird `piecewise_construct` arguments to it, too.

Comment: [Example of `piecewise_construct` with `emplace`.](http://ideone.com/V8TXah)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All standard library containers define a `value_type` member type, and their interfaces generically operate in terms of this `value_type`: `insert`, `push_back`, `push_front`. The new interface `emplace` adds a way of constructing a `value_type` object as if by:

```
value_type(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
```

Basically, there is no special interface provided for the satellite-data associative containers (i.e. maps) which is aware of the special structure of `value_type` (which is defined, not perfectly well-known, to be`pair<const key_type, mapped_type>`), with the exception of `find` and `erase` and `operator[]`, which take `key_type` arguments.

It is perhaps an oversight of the standard, or perhaps it was never deemed to be a problem, since you can always use `make_pair`, `make_tuple` or `forward_as_tuple`, or `emplace`, to create map value types.

(There is one problem with `insert` and move-only mapped types that has surfaced and is subject of [this recent proposal](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3873.html).)

Comment: Exception list is quite long: `at`, `count`, `equal_range`, `lower_bound`, `upper_bound`. Method that need `pair` is just one: `insert`.

Comment: @Ajay: Fair enough. On the other hand, `insert` and `emplace` are more general and exist for all containers, so the consistency of the big picture is important. Only specialized algorithms (i.e. members which are better than the corresponding free algorithm) can take advantage of special properties of the container. (Also, they have a lot more *overloads*.) By the way lower/upper bound is only for ordered containers, not for unordered ones.)